# prototype extending of NodeList

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using "html5" node.js library, based on "jsdom" library (https://github.com/aredridel/html5)

My code is:

```
var  HTML5 = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/html5/lib/html5'),
     Script = process.binding('evals').Script,
     util = require('util'),
     fs = require('fs');
var p = new HTML5.Parser();
p.parse_fragment(fs.readFileSync('test.xml'));
```

Now I have `p` object which has `p.tree.body_pointer._childNodes` of `NodeList`
(try p.tree.body_pointer._childNodes.constructor to see that).

I want to extend it by my method to be able calling `p.tree.body_pointer._childNodes.foo()`.

I tried NodeList.prototype.foo = function(){ return "OK"} but I get **NodeList is not defined** error message.

I guess NodeList is declared inside something I can't find. Looking in the source code I found it under `core` or `dom` but both are not available from my code.

Also I scaned HTML5 object - but no success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to bump an old thread, however it was my first search result on Google when searching for how to expand the NodeList prototype.

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to assign any value or function to a prototype.

Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'foo', {
    value: function() {
        // Return the lenght of the current NodeList
        return this.length;
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right :), now NodeList is available (i.e. it's on window object). Back they in 2013, when the question was asked, it wasn't - that's why I needed the trick. Good update answer!

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions I can think of:

```
// either ...
var NodeList = p.tree.body_pointer._childNodes.constructor;
// ...or...
var core = require('html5/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level3/core');
var NodeList = core.dom.level3.core.NodeList;
// ...or...
var jsdom = require('html5/node_modules/jsdom');
var NodeList = jsdom.dom.level3.core.NodeList;
// ...and then...
NodeList.prototype.foo = function() { ... };
```

All three aren't real pretty, though.